# Split exact sequence of linear maps implies split exact sequence of linear hom maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, exact-sequence

> If the exact sequence of left $A$-modules
>   $$0\xrightarrow{}F'\xrightarrow{u}F\xrightarrow{v}F''\xrightarrow{}0$$
>   splits, the sequence
>   $$0\xrightarrow{}\text{Hom}(E,F')\xrightarrow{\bar{u}}\text{Hom}(E,F)\xrightarrow{\bar{v}}\text{Hom}(E,F'')\xrightarrow{}0$$
>   is exact and splits, where $\bar{u}=\text{Hom}(1_E,u)$ and
>   $\bar{v}=\text{Hom}(1_E,v)$.
>
> The assertion follows from the fact that
>   $\text{Hom}(E,F')\oplus\text{Hom}(E,F'')$ is canonically identified
>   with $\text{Hom}(E,F'\oplus F'')$ by means of the mapping
>   $\text{Hom}(1_E,j')+\text{Hom}(1_E,j'')$, where  $j':F'\rightarrow
>  F'\oplus F''$ and $j'':F''\rightarrow F'\oplus F''$ are the canonical
>   injection.

To show that the sequence is exact and splits, I need to show the following: (1) injectivity of $\bar{u}$, (2) $\text{Im}(\bar{u})=\text{Ker}(\bar{v})$, (3) surjectivity of $\bar{v}$ and (4) the existence of a linear section of $\bar{v}$ (or a linear retraction of $\bar{u})$. (1) and (2) follow from the fact that 
$$0\xrightarrow{}F'\xrightarrow{u}F\xrightarrow{v}F''$$
is an exact sequence. Since the first sequence splits, there exists an $A$-linear mapping $s:F''\rightarrow F$ such that $v\circ s=1_{F''}$. Thus
$$\text{Hom}(1_E,v)\circ\text{Hom}(1_E,s)=\text{Hom}(1_E,v\circ s)=\text{Hom}(1_E,1_{F''}).$$
Hence, $\text{Hom}(1_E,v)$ has a section: i.e. it's surjective. Therefore the second sequence splits and is exact.

Now, I don't understand how my proof relates to the author's suggested method. Can someone please explain to me how the canonical identification proposed also proves the claim?

Comment: Just a comment to say that in my opinion the proof you suggest is much better than the other one.